# Use UDF from Add-in in Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, excel-2007, user-defined-functions, conditional-formatting

I have an add-in xla file that I use to store my regularly used VBA code. This function is stored in the add-in modules.

```
Public Function IsFormula(cell_ref As Range)
    IsFormula = cell_ref.HasFormula
End Function
```

This correctly returns True or False if I type it into cell: `=IsFormula(A1)`

However, when I try to create a new formatting rule using the formula option, I get this error 'You cannot use references to other worksheets or workbooks for Conditional Formating criteria.' The error is not because of quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't exactly a clear question to be answered here, but if you want to format say all of the cells in Sheet1 that contain formulae then, in Sheet1 A1:

1)  define a name (say ‘Formulaic’, with ‘Sheet1’ for “Scope” and `=GET.CELL(48,A1)` for “Refers to”.

2)  Select Sheet1

3)  Set required conditional format with “Use a formula to determine which cells to format” and `=Formulaic` in “Format values where this formula is true:”

The ‘type_num’ (eg 48 above) is described at http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/20611-info-only-get-cell-arguments.html